# Android AlertDialog does not show Adapter names

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-alertdialog

I made a AllertDialog that's supposed to display a list of apps, when I click on one of the alerdialog members it does return the right String from the ArrayAdapter.

Here's how it looks.

[image: current look of the dialog]

```
    public class AppList {

    private Activity main_activity;
    private AlertDialog app_list_dialog;

    private ArrayList<RemoteAppDetail> remoteAppDetails;

    public AppList(Activity activity){
        this.main_activity = activity;
//      init();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the Dialog, this needs to be called before .show()/.hide().dispose();
     */
    public void init(){
        this.remoteAppDetails = ConnectionHandler.getLibrary();

        AlertDialog.Builder app_list_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(main_activity);
        app_list_builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_input_add);
        app_list_builder.setTitle("Installable/Updatable Apps: ");

        final ArrayAdapter<String> app_list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(main_activity, R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        final ArrayList<String> app_name_list = getInstallableApps();

        app_list.addAll(app_name_list);


        if(!app_list.isEmpty()){
            //Add the app_list adapter (The button list)
            app_list_builder.setAdapter(app_list, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.i("DIALOG SELECTED", app_list.getItem(which));
                }
            });
        }else{
            app_list_builder.setMessage("There are no apps available for download/update.");
        }

        //Close Button AppList
        app_list_builder.setNegativeButton("Close", 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        this.app_list_dialog = app_list_builder.create();
    }


    /**
     * Show the list.
     */
    public void show(){
        if(this.app_list_dialog != null){
            app_list_dialog.show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hide the list.
     */
    public void hide(){
        if(this.app_list_dialog != null){
            app_list_dialog.hide();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Disposes the list, it will need to be reinitialized of you change your mind after disposing of the list.
     */
    public void dispose(){
        if(this.app_list_dialog != null){
            app_list_dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets a list of apps that can be installed
     * @return Arraylist installable apps
     */
    private ArrayList<String> getInstallableApps(){
        ArrayList<String> installable_apps_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(this.remoteAppDetails != null){
            for(RemoteAppDetail rea : this.remoteAppDetails){
                BasicNameValuePair remote_app_info = new BasicNameValuePair(rea.filename, String.valueOf(rea.version));
                BasicNameValuePair local_app_info = getLocalAppInfo(rea.filename);

                if(local_app_info != null){             
                    if(isRemoteVersionNewer(remote_app_info, local_app_info)){
                        installable_apps_list.add(rea.filename);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(rea.unlock_status == 0){
                        installable_apps_list.add(rea.filename);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return installable_apps_list;
    }


    /**
     * Check if the app exists locally.
     * @param app_name_remote
     * @return Local app info as BasicNameValuePair
     */
    private BasicNameValuePair getLocalAppInfo(String app_name_remote){
        List<PackageInfo> packs = main_activity.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        for(PackageInfo pi : packs){
            String app_name_local = pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(main_activity.getPackageManager()).toString();
            String app_version = String.valueOf(pi.versionCode);
            if(app_name_remote == app_name_local){
                return new BasicNameValuePair(app_name_local, app_version);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Compare local and remote app info.
     * @param remote_app_info
     * @param local_app_info
     * @return Return whether or not the remote version is newer as Boolean.
     */
    private boolean isRemoteVersionNewer(BasicNameValuePair remote_app_info, BasicNameValuePair local_app_info){
        if(remote_app_info.getName().contains(local_app_info.getName())){
            if(remote_app_info.getValue() == local_app_info.getValue()){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

So I would really like to know what I did wrong and if this is enough information.

**UPDATE 1:**
This is how I call this class:

```
Applist main_app_list = new Applist(this);
        main_app_list.init();
        main_app_list.show();
```

and it's called like that in my main activity's `onCreate` method.

Someone suggested my `getInstallableApps()` might return empty value's,
However if you inspect the code carefully this is not a possibility. Because if they there were empty it wouldn't even have any adapter members.

Either way I added some test value's, and it remains to do the exact same thing:

```
        final ArrayAdapter<String> app_list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(main_activity, R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        final ArrayList<String> app_name_list = getInstallableApps();

//      app_list.addAll(app_name_list);

        app_list.add("TEST");
        app_list.add("TEST2");
```

The rest of the code remains the same.

**UPDATE 2:**

When I touch one of the members, it show's their name for a brief second, or when I hold it down it show's them for as long as I hold it.

Comment: How are you calling this class?
Also in the code a call to init() is commented out in the constructor. In you working application i hope its not commented.

Comment: I basically initialize this class in my main activity as `app_list = new AppList(this);` in the `onCreate()` method and I open it like this.
`app_list.init() app_list.show();`

Comment: @Deb check my update you will see that this won't be the issue

Comment: it may be possible some theme issue.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela what kind of info do you need from me to see if this might be the case?

Comment: share your styles.xml

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela it's the stock styles.xml I havn't editted it at all. But have you read my latest update?

Comment: yes i read, that only suggests that the text font color or listitem background color is the issue. when you press list item, either font color changes or background color of listitem is changed and making the text visible.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I think this might very well be the case, can you post an answer that shows how to change the font color of the adapter? Then I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your `getInstallableApps()` method, you will see that it's entering the `for` statement because there are two elements in `this.remoteAppDetails`, but inside wether the elements you take data from are not called properly or empty (`remote_app_info`,`local_app_info`), or the filename field is empty. Once you find whats is placing empty values to you array you can fix it.

Comment: `Log.i("DIALOG SELECTED", app_list.getItem(which));`  in the `onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)` it logs the proper value, that it should also be showing, so that means the value's aren't empty. but its not showing them.

Comment: I just added extra information to show that this is not the case.

Comment: After the calls .init() and .show(), do you make any setContentView()?

Answer (score 0):

So I just ended up forcing the color to fix this since a custom layout was to much hassle for just this.

```
        app_list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(main_activity, R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice){
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                return textView;
                }
        };
```

For future reference when you think it doesn't show adapter names, just hold down on one of the members to see if it show's the member name, if it does you know you got a font problem.